# Hyperbolic subgroups of general linear groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory

Is there a classification of hyperbolic subgroups of $GL_n(A)$ for $A$ some ring of characteristic $p$? $A$ for me is a finitely presented algebra over a finite field.

More precisely I'm looking for a large hyperbolic subgroup $H$ of $GL_n(A)$ for some $n\geq 2$ (  the value of $n$ doesn't matter it just needs to be greater than $1$) which ideally $\mathbb{Z}[H]=M_n(A)$.

Edit: There might be some confusion about $\mathbb{Z}[H]$. Generally when you define a group ring the elements are formal sums of elements of $H$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, but here I mean you actually compute the sum in $M_n(A)$, it is not just a formal sum.
The question is whether you can write every element of $M_n(A)$ as sum of elements of $H$ with integer coefficients.

If it helps you can assume $A$ is the coordinate ring of some affine chart of a smooth projective variety over a finite field.

Comment: What do you mean by "hyperbolic"? Gromov-hyperbolic?

Comment: Correct. Gromov/Word-Hyperbolic

Comment: Does large mean $\mathbb Z[H]=M_n(A)$ for you? Also I am guessing you want non-elementary $H$ (which would imply you have a "large" subgroup in the technical sense, which means it has a finite index subgroup which surjects onto nonabelian free group)

Comment: Yes that is what I mean by large. Sorry I'm not an expert in the field so I don't know the correct terminology. $H$ can be elementary. I was actually trying to find such a group which is generated by elementary matrices (If that is what you mean by elementary!).

Comment: By the Tits alternative, there are free subgroups (which are word-hyperbolic). I think one can also arrange that the subgroup is Zariski dense (which ought to imply that $Z[H]=M_n(A)$ or something like that). I doubt that any classification of any sort is known.  See question 2 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05163

Comment: @PaulPlummer, how does your assertion in parentheses follow? There are non-elementary hyperbolic groups that are linear but not “large”.

Comment: @IanAgol, there should be both Zariski-dense and Zariski non-dense free subgroups H. But Z[H] depends only on the isomorphism type of H; so how can Zariski-density imply that Z[H]=M_n(A)?

Comment: @HJRW Does my recent edits address your question?

Comment: @ IanAgol the theorems you are referring to all are about general linear groups in a global field which means I have to take the fraction field. But the general linear groups in A are much smaller. For example the determinant has to be invertible in A.

Comment: Assume $n=2$ and $A=\mathbb{F}_q[x_1, \cdots, x_n]/I$. Is the group generated by \begin{equation} I_2, \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&x_i\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\x_i&1 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation} for all $i$ hyperbolic?

Comment: @HJRW Sorry for the ambiguous phrasing. The parenthetical was about $GL_n(A)$ containing a large hyperbolic subgroup, which if it contains a non elementary hyperbolic subgroup then it also contains non abelian free subgroups, which are large.

Comment: Tits alternative still applies if you can pass to a fraction field because your original linear group will be a subgroup of the general linear group of the field

Comment: @PaulPlummer -- thanks; I see what you had in mind now.

Comment: @user127776 : you’re right that the Tits alternative doesn’t necessarily apply. But it should in the case of A a  coordinate ring of a variety over a finite field by passing to the field of functions, as Paul notes. More generally when A is a product of integral domains, or even a subring  of a product of integral domains. But I’m not sure if there’s a version of Tits alternative over arbitrary commutative rings with unity.

Comment: @IanAgol That is correct but doesn't it at best imply that every element of $M_n(A)$ is a linear combination with integer coefficients of of some hyperbolic subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ ($K$is the fraction field of $A$) not $GL_n(A)$?

Comment: A remark regarding the discussion in the comments: A little bit of a commutative algebra ensures the Tits alternative over any commutative ring with 1 R: a f.g subgroup of GL_n(R) which is not v. solvable contains a non-abelian free group.

Comment: @user127776: yes, but it's possible it might span $GL_n(A')$, where $A'$ is the ring spanned by entries of the subgroup. Zariski density might not suffice, but I'm guessing something like this can be arranged.

Comment: @user127776: yes, that clarifies things. Thanks!

Comment: @HJRW You mentioned that there should be Zariski dense free subgroup but in the papers I have found, they prove it only for $GL_n(K)$ for some local field $K$. Our field here is not local. Could please point me to a reference which proves it in the non-local case?

Comment: @user127776, I don't know a reference, but I think there should be people on MO who do.  This would make a nice separate question.